# Accessing an application's 'Save Dialog' window, which has already been opened

Tags: c#

I already know the window title and can get control of the window using FindWindow(), and can send keystrokes and save the file, but I'm unable to specify save location, any ideas how I might do this?

```
int hwnd1 = 0;
            IntPtr hwndChild1 = IntPtr.Zero;
            hwnd1 = FindWindow(null, "Save Print Output As");

            while (hwnd1 == 0)
            {
                hwnd1 = FindWindow(null, "Save Print Output As");
                Thread.Sleep(250);

            }
```

Comment: Dare I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: The report gets saved into a temporary folder, before being uploaded to the application. Perhaps 40 of these are actioned per day in the department, so time is saved by automating it. I already have a script which generates a different report and want to include this functionality within the same script.

Comment: [A better approach would be to use Windows' UI Accessibility+Automation features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility-and-ui-automation-compared) - that way you can manipulate the dialog at a higher-level instead of hoping you send the right `SendMessage` commands (which will break whenever the Save Dialog is redesigned)